# vb.net How to make html or text file with encode in utf8

Tags: vb.net

can someone help me, how to make HTML or text file with utf8 using vb.net?

i make text using bellow code, but if the text contain utf 8, the result not in utf8 code..

```
   Dim Writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("directory/utf8.html")
       Writer.WriteLine("UTF 8 CODE HERE!!!")
       Writer.Close()
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the encoding in the Streamwriter constructor:

```
Dim Writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("directory/utf8.html", False, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

I believe the default is already UTF-8.

If you are asking how to output bytes that have already been converted to UTF-8, you can use WriteAllBytes:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("directory/utf8.html", b) ' b is a byte array
```